# Is there a way to programmatically read a macro description?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using Excel for Mac 2011. It's very easy to programmatically add a description to a macro using `Application.MacroOptions(macroName, macroDesc)`. However, how do you read that description programmatically?

For reasons required for the project, I am redesigning a macro dialog with some customizable options, including editing a macro description. So I have a pop up where the user can input a macro description for a macro, however, I want to also be able to then read the description to be able to show what the current description is (or at least what the current description has become after the user changes the description).

Comment: Reading similar past requests and function documentation, seems that this is not possible. `.MacroOptions` is listed as a Method hence it would not return any output. A potential workaround is hinted on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8882204/displaying-macrooptions though could not confirm if it produces your requirements. Regards,

Comment: For current description, can't you just output `macroDesc`?

Comment: findwindow, yes. However I also need to be able to show the description that the user defined in the future if the dialog is opened (even if it is a week later). So essentially... there is a window which shows the current description, then the user changes the description (which updates textbox with the old description), and finally next time the user runs the macro the current description shows what the newly updated description is. Based on nbayly's response and that post, this doesn't look promising. However, I am currently looking into seeing if a registry can do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nbayly references cpearsons site [here](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/vbe.aspx) which provides code that can access VBA text.  It seems there are many security downsides of enabling this sort of code in a production excel workbook.

I had a thought.  Perhaps you could:

1. use the code in the workbook to create a hidden worksheet that has a list of all macros and their descriptions. (Then disable the code and references you added).
2. Your dialogue then adds to this list when new macros are created

By doing the above you only have to use Application.MacroOptions(macroName, macroDesc) to write the description and as you also keep a copy in a worksheet you never need to read it.

Just a thought, any good?

Comment: That's a pretty good suggestion that I didn't consider highly to be honest. I tend to lean to this kind of "cheap solution" normally, but shy'd away from it at first because I wasn't sure if I could do that, given that the macros are in a .xlam file (add-in file). However, this is likely possible and should work. Before I try it though, I think I want to look into registries a bit more because, the more I look into them, it seems they will do the job well enough (for a local machine only).

Comment: 1. When you say "I wasn't sure if you could do that" I assume you're referring to getting the cpearson code working?  I know very little about registries - 2. are these the windows registries you refer to?  3. If you copy a workbook to another computer, will opening the workbook populate windows registries?  Hmm.  That sounds like a good way forwards if it does.  (The hidden worksheet would be kept in the xlam file)   Got to ask:  4. how many macros are there?  5. How easy would it be to manually create the hidden worksheet?)

Comment: 1. I was referring to the limitations of working with an xlam file (which I wasn't *very* familiar with. 2. Like these: [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/145679) 3. I'm not sure, but we are using a shared server anyway, so it shouldn't matter. 4. Around 30-50 depending on which workbook/add-in is being used. 5. Annoying enough that I'd write a script.

Comment: I'm no guru, but I've created xlam files a bit.  They are essentially just like workbooks, with all the usual objects (forms, ribbons etc). The VBA needs to use ThisWorkbook and ActiveWorkbook carefully as these objects give handles to their the addin's workbooks or the user's active open workbook.   From your other posts I figured you may know this already.  Just in case.   BTW.  I'm getting a bad feeling about working with the registry like this, it could so easily get out of step if you edit the workbook on another machine etc.